# Using Django, How can I delete a file right after downloaded without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, django

I have the next link to download a file that was generated before rendering a view:

`<a href="{% static download_path %}" download> Download File </a>`

How can I delete the file right after the user clicks on that link but without leaving the page?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean delete a file without refreshing the page?. You want to delete a file after user clicks on your link?

Comment: ajax call will help you

Comment: @kyore yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @c.grey I haven't found a way of deleting a file using Ajax with Django. Any examples with Django and Vue.js would be helpful.

Comment: @DannaCapellan Do see my answer and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a lot of details to work with so I will simply explain the steps that you have to follow. If you simply want to delete the file after it has been downloaded then following these should do just that.

Do note that you can't achieve Ajax by accessing a link in `urls.py`.

```
<a href="{% static download_path %}" download> Download File </a>
```

**To implement ajax based functionality**

> 1. Setup event handler
> 2. Create the AJAX request
> 3. Update the Django View
> 4. Handle the callback
> 5. Update the DOM

It's all well-elaborated [here](https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions-more-practice/). In terms of using Vue.js, you will have to incorporate that in the DOM manipulations according to your needs.